# Angular application communicating with the c# server over HTTPS

Tags: c#, angular, https

I have created an angular application that receives request from an outside world through my domain (my router static IP address with an alias `rejkid.hopto.org` e.g. `https:/rejkid.hopto.org:8080/scheduler`). I am using Tomcat 10 on port 8080.
I have configured NAT on my router so it routes all requests on port 8080 and 4000 to my server (local IP address 192.168.0.19).

I have configured Tomcat with the self signed SAN cercificate and imported that certificate to my windows cercificate database (under `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`). It looks like this:

```
Issuer:
CN = rejkid.hopto.org
OU = IT
O = OLOA
L = Sydney
S = NSW
C = AU
and SAN:
DNS Name=rejkid.hopto.org
IP Address=49.187.112.232
```

When I type in in my browser the request (e.g. https://rejkid.hopto.org/scheduler) it is all good, rquest is accepted - not complaint about cercificate. However from my angular app I also call the c# server on port 4000 (e.g. https://rejkid.hopto.org/:4000/accounts/register)
My environment.ts on the client site looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://rejkid.hopto.org/:4000'
};
```

The extract of the client code that makes the call looks like this:

```
const baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/accounts`;
refreshToken(account: Account) {
        return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/refresh-token`, account);
    }
```

The extract of my c# server code listening on the https requests looks like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseUrls("https://192.168.0.19:4000");
                        
                });
```

After that call (to the server on port 4000) I am getting (I see it when I open browser in development mode): Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.
I have learnet on this forum that no cercificate configuration is required on the c# side - but it seems that it is.

I apologise for the lengthy question. Can someone help to solve my issue please?

Comment: `environment.apiUrl` is invalid.

Comment: Why are you using Tomcat? That's for Java, but you're writing C#...

Comment: _"I have learned on this forum that no certificate configuration is required on the c# side"_ - no, that's untrue. It's just that VS's tooling for ASP.NET does it for you.

Comment: Any guess why am I getting `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`?

Comment: How can I point to browser which certificate to use for c# application